# What is the meaning/symbolism behind the spider, when Jesse and Saul are waiting for Walt?

Tags: analysis, breaking-bad

In the middle of the *Breaking Bad* episode entitled "Confessions", Jesse and Saul are waiting to meet Walt somewhere in the desert. As they are standing next to their car, the camera brings up a close shot of a big hairy spider, the same kind of spider as the killed boy, Drew Sharp, carried in a glass jar.

Is there any symbolism, or is this just a coincidence, this spider being of a common kind?

Comment: If you have your own theory, then you should rather post it as answer instead of putting it into the question (and thus making it a non-question).

Answer (score 7):

According to one fan theory, Fly represent Jesse and Todd represent spider. Fly can't be controlled but spider can be.

Here is elaborated detail-

> The fly represents the cause of Walt's problems, and I believe that is
>   Jesse Pinkman. This thread from a few days ago does a good job of
>   pointing that out [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/breakingbad/comments/1kjav2/jesse_is_the_real_cause_for_all_of_his_and_walts/).
>
> The fly is always out there causing problems, and he cannot be
>   contained by Walt despite all his efforts. There is reason to believe
>   that Jesse will be causing Walt even further problems in the next
>   episodes to come. I believe that the only way the fly can be
>   eliminated is from his natural predator, the spider, Todd. Todd has
>   consistently taken care of Walt's problems in the past, with the child
>   and the multiple hits on potential witnesses. Unlike the fly, the
>   spider is easily contained (kept in a jar) and reliable. Todd's most
>   recent actions were taking out that sleezebag's crew, who very well
>   may have caused further complications for Walt. If the buyers from the
>   Czech Republic who we keep hearing so much about continued to be
>   unsatisfied with the product, it could cause more trouble for Walt.
>
> Another thread mentioned that Jesse and Todd were opposites. Jesse is
>   a rude man with a conscious, and Todd is a gentleman without a
>   conscious. One could argue the fly and spider are opposites, or at
>   least conflicting forces since flies are prey to the spider. I believe
>   that we will see some sort of showdown between Jesse and Todd. The
>   result will cause either trouble or relief for Walt, depending on the
>   victor. One reason that comes to mind as to why Jess and Todd would
>   meet is that Jesse makes good meth. Todd may want to lure Jesse into
>   his web to make better meth in order to keep the satisfaction of the
>   buyers at a high level.
>
> (Source:[www.reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com/r/breakingbad/comments/1kvwsj/symbolism_of_the_spider_and_the_fly_spoilers/))

This theory was old and unaware to the end but still I feel its somewhere partially rite. Jesse looks fly to me too because of his free will, on the other hand Todd looks like a true assistant to me sometime for Walt and other time to his uncle, controllable like Spider which can be contained in jar.